# SQL Server 2012/BCP falhando - EOF inesperado

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Quero carregar alguns arquivos de dados do [Ministério da Educação](http://portal.inep.gov.br/basica-levantamentos-acessar) (Microdados do Censo da Educação Superior 2012) no meu SQL Server 2012 Express.

Os dados estão em arquivos coluna fixa gerados por algum programa escrito em Fortran.

Criei uma tabela seguindo o [dicionário de dados](https://hackathonparaeducacao.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/leia_me_censo_superior_2012.pdf) e usei o `bcp` para gerar um arquivo de formato:

```
bcp test.dbo.IES format nul -S SERVIDOR -c -f C:\Users\livisghton\Desktop\IES.fmt -T
```

Quando uso o `bcp` para carregar os dados, acontece o seguinte:

> C:\Users\lksa>bcp MCES_2012.dbo.IES IN C:\Users\lksa\Desktop\ies_amostra.txt -f ies.fmt -T -c
>   Aviso: -c substitui -f.
>
> Iniciando cópia...
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0] EOF inesperado encontrado no arquivo de dados BCP
>
> 0 linhas copiadas.
>   Tamanho do pacote de rede (bytes): 4096
>   Tempo total do relógio (ms.)     : 1

Alguma idéia do que está dando errado?

PS: Estou logado via autenticação do Windows, o arquivo está na área de trabalho, a conta do SQL Server tem acesso a minha área de trabalho e estou numa conta administrativa. O aquivo completo está no [ChopApp](http://chopapp.com/#ymkvysd9).

Até onde sei, os dados estão em Unicode sobre UTF-8.

As três primeiras linhas do arquivo são:

```
1310FACULDADE DE AMERICANA                                                                                                                                                                                       872       5Privada sem fins lucrativos                                                                                3Faculdade                                                                                            3501608AMERICANA                                                                                                                                                   35SPSudeste                              0     127       6       9       7       9      17      42      13      19       0       4       0       1       0       0       1       1       2   23316250.20          0.00     425201.80    3691699.00    3851526.20    1418442.40   12746316.20     255342.00          0.00    3235786.40
4358INSTITUTO FEDERAL DE EDUCAÇÃO, CIÊNCIA E TECNOLOGIA DO SUL DE MINAS GERAIS                                                                                                                                  8622       1Pública Federal                                                                                            4Instituto Federal de Educação, Ciência e Tecnologia                                                  3152501POUSO ALEGRE                                                                                                                                                31MGSudeste                              0     394      17       2      14       1      57      12       2       2      50      28      90      97      13       9       1       1       1    2675232.00  141722770.40      23902.80   33779272.80   21537198.60    6213781.40   36152500.80   44326708.00    1112226.80          0.00
790FACULDADE DE ENFERMAGEM DO HOSPITAL ISRAELITA ALBERT EINSTEIN                                                                                                                                                542       5Privada sem fins lucrativos                                                                                3Faculdade                                                                                            3550308SAO PAULO                                                                                                                                                   35SPSudeste                              1      28       0       0       0       0       4      10       4       6       2       2       0       0       0       0       1       1       1    2665000.00          0.00          0.00    2014000.00     160000.00     402750.00     708000.00    2750000.00          0.00          0.00
```

O arquivo de formato gerado pelo `bcp` é:

```
11.0
41
1       SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     1     CO_IES                                                     ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       200    "\t"     2     NO_IES                                                     Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     3     CO_MANTENEDORA                                             ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     4     CO_CATEGORIA_ADMINISTRATIVA                                ""
5       SQLCHAR             0       100    "\t"     5     DS_CATEGORIA_ADMINISTRATIVA                                Latin1_General_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     6     CO_ORGANIZACAO_ACADEMICA                                   ""
7       SQLCHAR             0       100    "\t"     7     DS_ORGANIZACAO_ACADEMICA                                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     8     CO_MUNICIPIO_IES                                           ""
9       SQLCHAR             0       150    "\t"     9     NO_MUNICIPIO_IES                                           Latin1_General_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     10    CO_UF_IES                                                  ""
11      SQLCHAR             0       2      "\t"     11    SGL_UF_IES                                                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR             0       30     "\t"     12    NO_REGIAO_IES                                              Latin1_General_CI_AS
13      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     13    IN_CAPITAL_IES                                             ""
14      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     14    QT_TEC_TOTAL                                               ""
15      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     15    QT_TEC_FUND_INCOMP_MASC                                    ""
16      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     16    QT_TEC_FUND_INCOMP_FEM                                     ""
17      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     17    QT_TEC_FUND_COMP_MASC                                      ""
18      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     18    QT_TEC_FUND_COMP_FEM                                       ""
19      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     19    QT_TEC_MEDIO_MASC                                          ""
20      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     20    QT_TEC_MEDIO_FEM                                           ""
21      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     21    QT_TEC_SUPERIOR_MASC                                       ""
22      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     22    QT_TEC_SUPERIOR_FEM                                        ""
23      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     23    QT_TEC_ESPEALIZACAO_MASC                                   ""
24      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     24    QT_TEC_ESPEALIZACAO_FEM                                    ""
25      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     25    QT_TEC_MESTRADO_MASC                                       ""
26      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     26    QT_TEC_MESTRADO_FEM                                        ""
27      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     27    QT_TEC_DOUTORADO_MASC                                      ""
28      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     28    QT_TEC_DOUTORADO_FEM     
29      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     29    IN_ACESSO_PORTAL_CAPES                                     ""
30      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     30    IN_ACESSO_OUTRAS_BASES                                     ""
31      SQLCHAR             0       8      "\t"     31    IN_REFERENTE                                               ""
32      SQLCHAR             0       14     "\t"     32    VL_RECEITA_PROPRIA                                         ""
33      SQLCHAR             0       14     "\t"     33    VL_TRANSFERENCIA                                           ""
34      SQLCHAR             0       14     "\t"     34    VL_OUTRA_RECEITA                                           ""
35      SQLCHAR             0       14     "\t"     35    VL_DES_PESSOAL_REM_DOCENTE                                 ""
36      SQLCHAR             0       14     "\t"     36    VL_DES_PESSOAL_REM_TECNICO                                 ""
37      SQLCHAR             0       14     "\t"     37    VL_DES_PESSOAL_REM_ENCARGO                                 ""
38      SQLCHAR             0       14     "\t"     38    VL_DES_CUSTEIRO                                            ""
39      SQLCHAR             0       14     "\t"     39    VL_DES_INSVESTIMENTO                                       ""
40      SQLCHAR             0       14     "\t"     40    VL_DES_PESQUISA                                            ""
41      SQLCHAR             0       14     ""   41    VL_DES_OUTRAS                                              ""
```

Comment: @gmsantos
Estou tentando, mas sem muito sucesso. Se você puder ajudar com isso, agradeço.

Comment: Estou usando, para formatar o código de linha de comando:
(linha em branco)
```
(linha em branco)
bcp ...
```
E não funciona.

Comment: Consegui editar. Quatro espaços no  lugar de backticks.

Answer (score 2):

Informa a quebra de linha na última coluna.

```
41      SQLCHAR             0       14     "\r\n"   41    VL_DES_OUTRAS
```